# Need a FullScreen JavaScript or any logic?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, web

Need a full screen where nothing appears excpet body part of my page. No task Bar at bottom and no title bar, addressbar, location bar, toolbar, command menu at top.

Need only HTML Body part to full Screen.
Googled a lot but could not get any appropriate which perform well in all browsers.

Comment: Pressing F11 does the job I think.

Comment: But I do not want user to press it manually. It should be done on page load, Any Idea? @SampritiPanda

Comment: Full Screen API: http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

You could try starting the browser up in Kiosk mode from the command line or a shortcut, most have browser have a way to do it.

For Chrome in Windows you can start it up from a command line with
START chrome.exe "THE-URL-YOU-WANT" --kiosk
or you can add --kiosk to the target in the desktop or taskbar shortcut properties (right-click -> properties) ie '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk'

or on a Mac use

cd /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --kiosk "THE-URL-YOU-WANT"

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different methods for the full screen API.

```
// Webkit (works in Safari and Chrome )
element.webkitRequestFullScreen(); 
document.webkitCancelFullScreen(); 

// Firefox
element.mozRequestFullScreen();
document.mozCancelFullScreen();
```

For a more comprehensive guide, read through this article on the FullScreen API.

http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/

Comment: This probabely does not work in IE. I need full support in all browser. @Sampriti Panda

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly but if you need only a page to be fullscreen with javascript, you have to use a code like this:

`element.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var domPrefixes = 'webkit moz o ms khtml'.split(' '), i = 0, prefix = null;
      while(!(prefix = previewFrame[domPrefixes[i] + 'RequestFullScreen'])){ i++; }
      prefix.apply(this);
});`

**Important:** this code only works with a click or any other user interaction event. More informations at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API